# Alternative term for trivial case

Tags: technical

Probably a relatively technical term.
Commonly used for the case where, for example, two sets are equal because they are both empty.

"This instance of the problem has reduced down to the _____ case".

Trivial is very close but I have a feeling there's a better term too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be thinking about the *degenerate case*:

> *degenerate* 2:  being mathematically simpler (as by having a factor or constant equal to zero) than the typical case

([Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/degenerate))

Comment: Couldn't remember it either but I saw it in the "See also" section of Wikipedia's "Triviality" article.